# update mysql database from pandas dataframe

Tags: python, mysql, database, pandas, sql-update

I have a couple of dataframes that I store in a MySQL database. I want to update these database tables whenever the dataframes are updated. An example dataframe can be found below.

[image]

The code I now use adds new rows to the database when they are created on the dataframe and the PK is new. I however also want it to update product names when you change those. The code I now use is this:

```
for i in range(len(df)):
    try:
        df.iloc[i:i+1].to_sql(name="products",if_exists='append',con = engine,index=False)
    except exc.IntegrityError as e:
        pass
```

So the question, is there a way to update the database with new and changed rows in the dataframe without dropping it? Thanks in advance